# Problem with Get at M11.0 that was produced with DumpSave M12.1

Tags: compatibility, dumpsave

I have two computers, one has Mathematica 11.0, one has Mathematica 12.1.

I have created a .mx file using `DumpSave` at M12.1. I can read the .mx file using `Get` at that computer. and want to read it via `Get` at the machine with M11.0. However, `Get` doesn't show an error message, but the variable that is contained in the .mx is not in memory.

Is this a known problem?

My codes:

**1) At M12.1:**

```
testVar = x + y^2;
DumpSave[NotebookDirectory[] <> "mytestfile.mx", testVar]
```

I restart the kernel, and perform:

```
Get[NotebookDirectory[] <> "mytestfile.mx"]
Column@Thread@{Names["Global`*"], ByteCount[#] & /@ ToExpression /@ Names["Global`*"]}
```

shows the correct output `"{testVar", 128}`. Everything good.

**2) At M11.0:**
Now I copy the mytestfile.mx to the other computer, and load it in the same instruction.

```
Get[NotebookDirectory[] <> "mytestfile.mx"]
Column@Thread@{Names["Global`*"], ByteCount[#] & /@ ToExpression /@ Names["Global`*"]}
```

No error, but the variable is not in memory. Not good.

**Questions:**

- Is this a known bug?
- Is it a mistake on my side?
- Are there any workarounds? (it is impossible to recreate the .mx file at M11.0, it takes too long)

Comment: This is mentioned on the ref page for the  [MX](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/MX.html) format.  Is there any way to open the MX in version 12.1 and save it to a different format?

Comment: Can you move them the other direction? From 11.0 to 12.1?

Comment: @JasonB. You are right, thanks a lot, it is written that `MX files created by newer versions of the Wolfram System may not be usable by older versions.`. I tried `Save` now, and it works (but made the files roughly twice the size, and they where already 100s of MBs). Do you have any explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: Save is probably using a plain text format, which is version independent but larger than a binary format like MX

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that

> Files written by DumpSave cannot be exchanged between operating systems that differ in $SystemWordLength.

which is quoted from the documentation article on `DumpSace`, is relevant to your problem. Evaluated `$SystemWordLength` on both computers. Are they different?

Comment: Thanks for this. I checked, and `$SystemWordLength=64` at both machines.